# Nested ui-sref in angular-google-map info window

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to pass the id of the object via `ui-sref` directive to no avail.

My markup:

```
<div class="row" ui-gmap-google-map
 center="map.center"
 zoom="map.zoom"
 options="map.options"
 control="map.control"
 events="map.events">
<div ui-gmap-markers models="events" coords="'location'" idkey="'_id'">
    <div ui-gmap-windows show="showInfo" ng-cloak>
        <div class="text-center" style="position: relative" ui-sref="event.view({id: this._id})">
            <h5 ng-non-bindable>{{::name}}</h5>
            <div ng-non-bindable>
                <img style="width: 125px" src="{{::pictures[0]}}" alt="Image not available">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything is working via data binding. When clicking the window area the route changes but the `id` parameter is always empty in `$stateParams`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: what is `this` referring to here?  why not `id: _id`?

Comment: I've tried this too. didn't seem to work.